# Have Excel move user input into another sheet and clear the original sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, automation, user, input, copy

I did quite some looking around trying to find a solution for this but came up empty.

What we are trying to do is build an excel file that basically has 3 sections. We want to use it to monitor the consumption of goods.

1. A sheet where the user (factory) gives input (how much of what has been consumed).
2. "Archive" with all the data
3. Analysis of consumption

I am looking for a way that would allow the guys in the factory to just hack in what they used. Excel then copies this data into a second sheet ("Archive") - date, what, how much... into the next empty row. A third sheet then uses the data from the second sheet to do some basic analysis for the production leader to see how much material is consumed where.

I am not sure how to realize this, here are the problems that I am facing:

- automatically copy data into a new, empty row
- automatically delete said data from the input cells when closing the file
- When the guys in production close and open the file, macros are typically deactivated, meaning any VBA is inactive as well

Does anyone have a good idea here?
It does not have to be the exact same thing that I am describing.

Thank you so much!

Comment: It sounds like you want a (basic) database in Excel but without VBA. I've built the kind of thing you're talking about but it relied on VBA to copy the data and clear the form. AFAIK, there is no way to do what you're asking completely within Excel but without VBA. It *could* be done with a small Access database, though, if that's an available option.

Comment: Well... we use access databases - some indian guy is managing that for us. none of us has a license for it. and the file format is older than access 97... Let's just say it won't work with access.

But I can still use VBA, we'll just have to train the guys to activate macros

Comment: What version of office are you using. If it's M365 (or Office 365) and you have access to the program known as FORMS. If so this video might give you some ideas. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nXeYv-W-Wt4

Comment: Thank you @BradR, I will look into it.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming your data is / will be in a sensible data format with column headings and one row per entry.

If so, you could use the built in, but not often used, and hard to find, "form" feature of Excel. Caveat - if you have loads (>25) columns, it gets pretty hard work for the user because of scrolling up and down. And there's no data validation etc. But it is really easy to try out and see if it would help you.

You need to add the Form button to the Quick Access Toolbar (QAT). It can be found in the section "Commands Not in the Ribbon" then scroll to find "Form" and add it to the QAT. With a bit more work you could add this to a custom Ribbon if you really wanted to.

Build your data area / table.
Select a cell in any row which has data, or the first row below that*, and then click your new "form" button.
Excel presents you with a form where you can view existing data one record at a time, with fields (columns) as a single column rather than scrolling around.
Click "New" to add a new row of data, and when finished, click "New" to do "Save and next".

Not a perfect solution at all, but free and might help users who are less Excel-savvy (you need to teach them to click a couple of buttons). To be honest, your requirement sounds like a perfect use case for a simple database or an online forms tool like MS Forms (or google equivalent).

*If you use a Ctrl-T table for your data (often a good idea), you have to click a row in the table, not the row below it. Not a big deal but a minor snag.